# Is renaming a folder in SVN a good idea?

Tags: svn, project-management

I have the following SVN (standard) structure:

```
Project1
    trunk
    tags
    branches
```

Project1 is the project code name.  After it is done, it is shifted to a Product.  The problem is that after a year, I forget the project name for the product.  I'd like to rename the SVN Project1 to Product1.

Are there any gotchas that will come from this?

Comment: With your specific example, why does it matter? And if it does matter, why not just dump a text file at the root level that says "this was originally named Project1"?

Comment: (and, yes, I understand that there are questions of revision history, but with a mature product you rarely care about the revision history of any prototype, except to say "yeah, George did this, glad we fired him")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did this kind of things several times and didn't get any special problems.

As much as I remember, most important thing is to commit all changes from all local directories (especially if there are several developers) before you change the name. After you change the project name, the path is changed and you cannot use the "switch" option of the TortoiseSVN and you will need to use "SVN Checkout" to start working on the project again.

Answer (score 4):

```
svn help mv
```

---

```
move (mv, rename, ren): Move and/or rename something in working copy or repository.
usage: move SRC... DST
```

One more reason to use this command instead of deleting and then recreating(looks easier at first sight) is that SVN history for this file/folder won't be lost.

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```
svn rename
```

but remember to commit after you rename, otherwise there might be issues. For further details read this

http://juicebar.wordpress.com/2007/05/04/svn-rename-pitfalls-to-avoid/

Answer (score 2):

People having local copies can relocate.

Gotchas I can think of:

- Adapt the automatic build tools or CI server to the right path
- If you made use of svn:externals take care of redirecting them too
- and the rights defined in the svn server config files, check the paths
- And not to forget the commit/revision... hook scripts.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that appropriate naming is something important enough, as to change it as needed.

You have to rename in SVN, not only in your environment.

With TortoiseSVN, this happens with a mouse right-drag ! Tricky maneuver :-)

Take care of impacting also scripts and so on...